# Event to do something when the user slides up on the last page in UIPageViewController swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to run code when the user tries to move to the next page when there is no more pages in UIPageViewController.
screencast example (when the user swipe up I want to change category to feed):
http://d.pr/i/1jnNK

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ? Which code you are trying to execute ?
Why not use the viewControllerBeforeViewController and check if it's the last VC to show and execute your code from there ?

Comment: I want to execute the code after the user has swiped up and found up this is the last page and then move him to other page

Comment: Again, so why not use the viewControllerBeforeViewController to detect if it's the last page and execute your code ?
Also, what do you mean "move him to other page" ? Does it mean to navigate modal/push to stack ?

Comment: Yes to navigate to different page. I want it to happen when he tries to swipe up, not before he swipes (you can see in the video what I mean)

Comment: So why not self.navigationController.push.... inside viewControllerBeforeViewController when you reach the first VC ?